# How to put a lot of XMLs together and transform it in Windows

Tags: xml, windows, xslt, cmd

I have a lot of XML files in folders - one XML for one page of a book. I need to put all the XMLs together in one root XML file and then make first transformation using XSL for removing namespaces and unwanted attributes (I have a XSL stylesheet for that), save the new XML and than transform it again using another stylesheet (I have prepared it too) and save the result text file.
I do it at home in Oxygen with one XML file, but I need to make this process automatic, run it with some script. I must work in Windows and without Oxygen, customer has not any software for it and wants to make it by himself.
How to put XMLs together without writing a root XML with !ENTITY tags? What software tools (for XSL transformation) can I use? How to make such script for Windows?
I do programming in Python and a little in Java.
Thank you very much.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

See the XSLT specification on how to use [multiple source documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#document).

Answer (score 0):

For putting the XML files together so that you can process them as one file, one option would be to to write a cmd.exe batch script which produces a root XML file with external entity references to all your XML files.

Perhaps something like this (assuming the XML file names without the extension are allowed entity names):

```
@echo off
del root.xml 2> nul
(
    echo ^<!DOCTYPE root [
    for %%f in (*.xml) do (echo ^<!ENTITY %%~nf SYSTEM "%%f"^>)
    echo ]^>
    echo ^<root^>
    for %%f in (*.xml) do (echo ^&%%~nf;)
    echo ^</root^>
) > root.tmp
move root.tmp root.xml > nul
```

Alternatively, you could just output the file names using some XML tags, and access the files using the `document()` function from your XSLT.

For running a XSLT transformation from the command line, you could use for example the [msxsl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) command line utility, which is a frontend to the MSXML library probably already installed on your system.

```
msxsl root.xml stylesheet.xsl
```